# How to send excel sheet as attachment in HTML email in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I want to send an Employee details excel sheet as attachment in HTML email in shell script. I tried with below code but couldn't able to do it.

Please help on this.

```
    if [[ -f /x/project/Emp_Report.xlsx ]]; then

    echo "Employee Report exists !!"
    (
        echo "From: abc@gmail.com"
        echo "To: xyz@gmail.com"
        echo "cc: pqr@gmail.com"
        echo "Subject:Employee Report"
        echo "Content-Type: TEXT/HTML, multipart/mixed, text/html, application/octet-stream"
        echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
        echo "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=/x/project/Emp_Report.xlsx"
        echo "<html>"
        echo "<body>"
        echo "<p>Hi Team,</p>"
        echo "<p>Please find the Employee details in attachment.</p>"
        echo "<p>In case of any queries, kindly reach out to 'abc@gmail.com'</p>"
        echo "<b>Regards,</b><br>"
        echo "Abc"
        echo "</body></html>"
    ) |  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
    
    echo "Employee Report Mail hase been sent successfully !!"
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

1. need a blank line between the header and the body.
2. attachments require MIME email, so you need boundaries

The following is a snippet from an email-sending shell script in my arsenal: you'll need to change `text/plain`

```sh
    local boundary="_====-boundary-${$}-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)-====_"

    {
        echo "From: $from"
        echo "To: $to"
        echo "Cc: $cc"
        echo "Subject: $subject"
        echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\""
        echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
        echo
        echo "This is a multi-part message in MIME format."
        echo
        printf -- "--%s\n" "$boundary"
        echo "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        echo
        echo "$body"
        echo
        for filename in "${attachments[@]}"; do
            # attach it if it's readable and non-zero size
            if [[ -r "$filename" ]] && [[ -s "$filename" ]]; then
                printf -- "--%s\n" "$boundary"
                echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
                echo "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=$(basename "$filename")"
                echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$(basename "$filename")"
                echo
                base64 "$filename"
                echo
            fi
        done
        printf -- "--%s--\n" "$boundary"
    } | /usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t
```

Answer (score 0):

I gone through couple of sources and wrote the below code.

It works perfectly for me.

```
export ATTACHMENT=/x/project/Emp_Report.xlsx
EMAIL_BOUNDARY_STRING=Z${RANDOM}${RANDOM}${RANDOM}${RANDOM}

if [[ -f /x/project/Emp_Report.xlsx ]]; then
    echo "Employee Report exists !!"
    (
        echo "From: abc@gmail.com"
        echo "To: xyz@gmail.com"
        echo "cc: pqr@gmail.com"
        echo "Subject:Employee Report"
        echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
        echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="${EMAIL_BOUNDARY_STRING}"'
        echo '--${EMAIL_BOUNDARY_STRING}'
        
        echo "Content-Type: text/html"
        echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
        echo "<html>"
        echo "<body>"
        echo "<p>Hi Team,</p>"
        echo "<p>Please find the Employee details in attachment.</p>"
        echo "<p>In case of any queries, kindly reach out to 'abc@gmail.com'</p>"
        echo "<b>Regards,</b><br>"
        echo "Abc"
        echo "</body></html>"
        echo '--${EMAIL_BOUNDARY_STRING}'
    
        echo 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="'$(basename $ATTACHMENT)'"'
        echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
        echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACHMENT)'"'
        uuencode -m $ATTACHMENT $(basename $ATTACHMENT)
    
    ) |  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
    
    echo "Employee Report Mail hase been sent successfully !!"
fi
```